# Can I use raspberry Pi and my old nokia 8500 xpressmusic to create a project?

Tags: home-automation

I was wondering if the screen, camera or any other components could be used with a raspberry Pi to create a project? Like creating a home security camera or something.

Cheers

Comment: Of course you can use two pieces of technology to built a third, but the effort required is hard to determin if you do not state any more specifics. Theoretically, you can always solder everything apart, solder it together in a different way and write a firmware/drivers from scratch. I assume, you do not want to solder and would like to use existing drivers/firmwares?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fantilein1990's comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/54871/fantilein1990) pretty much sums it up, while your phone does have a camera and a screen, getting them to interact with the Pi will be a ton of work. If you're interested those kind of components, there are of course the [Raspberry Pi Camera module](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/camera-module/) and [PiTFT touch screen](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1601), both designed specifically for the Raspberry Pi. These are directly compatible, and have both first and third-party support (from the manufacturer and the community), whereas I suspect you will have little to no luck finding documentation on the components from your Nokia.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll look into these products then.